# Excel macro - screen while macro runs

Tags: layout, user-interface, excel, vba

When I run my macro is can see it switching sheets and copy/pasting data. But this isn't really user-friendly. Is there a way to show a simple messagebox "The macro is running!" for the entire duration and OK only becomes clickable when the macro stops?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code use:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

//Your code

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This will stop the screen flicker you are seeing...